# JS - Why isn't my JavaScript src working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an excerpt from my code:

```
<form name="calculator">
<input type="button" name="latest" value="You are not using the latest version.">
<script src="http://www.alvinneo.com/bulbuleatsfood.js">
if(latest-version==="1.0.4.2"){
document.calculator.latest.value="You are using the latest version.";
};
</script>
</form>
```

For some reason, this isn't working. Any tips?

Comment: You could give us a tip of what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: `script` tags with src must not contain code: `<script src="http://www.alvinneo.com/bulbuleatsfood.js"></script>`!

Comment: Well, without knowing anything about the way in which it isn't working, I can tell you that variables with hyphens in them are not allowed in JavaScript, so `latest-version` isn't going to fly.  Could try `latestVersion` or `latest_version` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [**docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> #### src:
>
> This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can
> be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a
> document. If a script element has a src attribute specified, it should
> not have a script embedded inside its tags.

Change your code to this:

```
<form name="calculator">
  <input type="button" name="latest" value="You are not using the latest version.">

  <!-- script with src (not containing embedded code) -->
  <script src="http://www.alvinneo.com/bulbuleatsfood.js"></script>

  <!-- another script (containing embedded code but not src) -->
  <script>
    if(latest-version === "1.0.4.2") {
      document.calculator.latest.value = "You are using the latest version.";
    };
  </script>
</form>
```